# Mongodb aggregating likert scale

Tags: mongodb

This seems like an easy question, but I can't seem to figure it out after trying for a substantial amount of time.

I have a mongodb collection that has the schema `{user, documentID, rating}`. Ratings are on a scale of 1-5, so the collection might look something like:

```
userA, documentA, 5
userA, documentB, 5
userB, documentA, 1
userC, documentB, 2
(and so on...)
```

Is there a way I can directly find the count of **each rating** on **a single document** with a single query? The desired output is something like:

```
documentA:{
    "1": 23,
    "2": 24,
    "3": 131,
    "4": 242,
    "5": 500
}
```

I've read about how to use `aggregate` to group fields but I'm not sure how it can be used to return the count of `distinct` values (ie 1-5).

Will really appreciate any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this using aggregation

the query would look like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $group: 
        { _id: { document: "$document", rating: "$rating"}, 
          sum: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

the output would be like

```
{_id: {"document": "documentA", "rating": 1}, "sum": 1}
{_id: {"document": "documentA", "rating": 5}, "sum": 1}
{_id: {"document": "documentB", "rating": 2}, "sum": 1}
{_id: {"document": "documentB", "rating": 5}, "sum": 1}
```